# How to place a wide figure with subfigures in Latex?

Tags: latex, subfigure

I am trying to write a report and stuck with a wide figure. My document type is PRL using revtex4.1 with two columns. I have a wide figure which consists of 8 subfigures. I am trying to place it bottom of a page but it insists to go next page. Here is code for my wide figure:

```
\begin{figure*}
\centering
\subfloat[s1]{\label{fig:s1}\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{s1.png}}\qquad
\subfloat[s2]{\label{fig:s2}\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{s2.png}}\qquad
\subfloat[s3]{\label{fig:s3}\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{s3.png}}\qquad
\subfloat[s4]{\label{fig:s4}\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{s4.png}}\\
\subfloat[s5]{\label{fig:s5}\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{s5.png}}\qquad
\subfloat[s6]{\label{fig:s6}\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{s6.png}}\qquad
\subfloat[s7]{\label{fig:s7}\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{s7.png}}\qquad
\subfloat[s8]{\label{fig:s8}\includegraphics[width=0.20\textwidth]{s8.png}}
\caption{\label{fig:s}Caption}
\end{figure*}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try also

```
\begin{figure*}[!hb]
```

If your figure is too wide, this might help: [Centering wide tables or figures](http://texblog.net/latex-archive/layout/centering-figure-table/).

Comment: They also don't work in this case. I just added wide figures as an appendix.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it will work, but have you tried using placements, ie:

```
\begin{figure*}[b]
```

where b stands for bottom?

You could also try using the float package (put this in the preamble, before \begin{document}:

```
\usepackage{float}
```

and then using

```
\begin{figure*}[H]
```

to specify exactly where you want your figure to be, i.e. put the figure exactly in the position in relation to your text where you want the figure to be placed.

It may be that your figure is just too big and it won't fit there, so you may have to reduce the size of the figures or fiddle with the margins (not recommended, but possible).

Lastly, in 6 days the [LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) question and answer website will be open to everyone, and you might find it useful.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to mention that I tried using placements before. No luck.